# Find biggest value in C using overflow and loop

Tags: java, c

The task is to find the biggest int value with a loop. I have the exact same code almost
in C and in Java. In Java it works fine, but in C I get the smallest value instead and
I would like to know why.

**C**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i+1 > 0; i++) { }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

**Java**

```java
public class Java {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i+1 > 0; i++) { }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know nasal demons, but this is still very surprising to me. What compiler/system are you on and what is the answer? There are 3 types of integer representations mandated by C17-: `int8_t 127+1` equals, 1's -127, 2's -128, SM -0.

Comment: @Neil: I was able to reproduce the problem on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) using OP's code with the latest gcc compiler, but not with clang. When I added the [`-fwrapv`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fwrapv) compiler command-line option, then OP's code also works on gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems to falsely assume that in C, an `int` is guaranteed to wrap to a negative number on [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). This assumption is wrong. Such a signed integer overflow will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C, so you cannot rely on any specific behavior if you let that happen.

In order to find the largest representable value of an `int`, you can use the macro constant [`INT_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits), which is defined in `limits.h`.

Note however that it is only **signed** integer overflow that invokes undefined behavior in C. In constrast to that, when using unsigned numbers, they are guaranteed to wrap in a well-defined manner. Therefore, you could find the largest representable `unsigned int` using your method.

Also, some compilers have a setting that will cause the behavior of signed integer overflow to become well-defined (assuming that your hardware supports it and uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for representing signed numbers, which is probably the case). In gcc and clang, you can use the [`-fwrapv`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fwrapv) compiler command-line option to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. This should not be an exercise in a beginner C class.

Comment: @NoCodeNoBlunder: Yes, this is a rather advanced topic. My guess is that your professor was probably unaware of the undefined behavior, or he made a false assumption that it would work as intended, despite it being undefined behavior.